# How do you use AcquireTokenSilentAsync to authenticate a user?

Tags: c#, azure, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am attempting to programmatically authorise an Azure application from an Azure AD joined machine.

If I go to the application URL in Internet Explorer it is able to verify the logged on user account.

My current code looks something like this:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTGUID");
Uri uri = new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
var pparams = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, null);
AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2", uri, pparams);
```

This call is successful but I want to acquire a token for the currently logged on user.

The first two parameters to the `AcquireTokenAsync` call are `resource` and `clientid`.

I can get the Homepage url and application id for the application I want to access but cannot find a combination of the two that works.

What parameters should I pass to this function to silently validate the logged on user and obtain an authorisation header that can be used in subsequent calls to the application?

Comment: you want something like ```https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token```

Comment: The resource is the identifier for the APO you want a token for. `https://graph.windows.net` is the identifier for Azure AD Graph API. `https://graph.microsoft.com` is the identifier for the Microsoft Graph API. It all depends on the token cache having some credentials in it though to work.

Comment: If I change to using oauth2/token I get the error AADSTS90002: Tenant token not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.

Comment: If I try to use the application clientid in place of graph.windows.net I get erros like the following: 
AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'CLIENTID'. 
AADSTS50001: The application named CLIENTNAME was not found in the tenant named TENANTGUID

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you now MSAL.NET [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa) for domain or AAD joined machines:

the code would be something like :

```
static async Task GetATokenForGraph()
{
 string tenant = "contoso.com" // can also be a GUID or organizations for multi-tenant
 string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}";
 string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
 PublicClientApplication app = new PublicClientApplication(clientId, authority);
 var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

 AuthenticationResult result=null;
 if (accounts.Any())
 {
 result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault());
 }
 else
 {
  try
  {
   result = await app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuthAsync(scopes);
  }
  catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
   { 
    // For details see the article
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
When I try the above, first no accounts are found then the AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuthAsync failes with the error
Win32Exception: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later

Comment: If I try using AcquireTokenAsync instead of AcquireTokenByIntegratedAuthAsync a sign-in windows pops up with the logged on user Id in it but when that Id is selected the following error occurs:
AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'CLIENTID'.

Comment: @Paul Dolphin. If the system cannot contact a domain controller, this is probably because your machine is not domain joined, or your VPN is down

Comment: For AcquireTokenAsync, this means that you need to check the urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob reply URI in your app registration. Please see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2